# Best tool for creating organizational charts?

Tags: charts, microsoft-visio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Application to help build diagrams](https://superuser.com/questions/67536/application-to-help-build-diagrams)

I need to find a Windows tool/software, or an online service, for creating organizational chart for the company I'm employed at.

I have tried several shareware solutions supposedly tailored for the job. Most tools are dead simple which renders them unusable. I have also tried the MS Office add-on, far too simple - complex structure are out of its league...

Haven't tried Visio, is it any good?

Any recommendations? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/) is the best one i have used, its what its built to do tbh. You can get additonal  add-ons and templates

Comment: Agreed, Visio is the most used and the best tool to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try the online tool [LucidChart](http://www.lucidchart.com/) its free up to a certain number of shapes. I used it recently when Visio started to get on my nerves - I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2007/2010's charting function makes very nice-looking and easily modified/updated org charts. Plus, if you have office you probably have Excel, and Visio is most likely an expensive extra option.

Use the Smart Art tool in the Insert ribbon to choose the appropriate chart form, then just start adding members in an ordered list.

Answer (score 0):

Visio is an obvious choice.

You can create [Org charts](https://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2004/05/06/graphviz_dot.html?page=2) in [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/).